# C#: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and i am having issues understanding this error. I have a class A which has a constructor that initializes a property which would be common to 2 of its children

```
public class A
{
  Property P1;
  public A(Property p1)
 {
    this.p1=p1;
 }
 }
```

I have a class B which derives from this class and its constructor initializes its own parameters as well

```
 public class B : A
 {
     Property p2:
     Property p1;
     public B(Property p2): base(p1)
    {
        this.p2=p2;
    }
   }
 }
```

I get an error in the constructor B "An object reference is required for the non static field , method, or property"
My goal is to just initialize property P2 in constructor B .I added the base (p1) as i got an error that there is no actual parameter which corresponds to the formal parameter. What is the right way to initialize both the parameters?

Comment: You cant pass in instance members to the base constructor, they need to be static or available through the derived constructor (as parameters), more than likely you want `public B(Property p2): base(p2)`

Comment: Right. And the reason, or part of it, is that there is no instance of derived available _yet_ at the point where `base(p2)` is. It is under construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your B constructor should look like this:

```
 public B(Property p1, Property p2): base(p1)
```

So `B` accepts `p1` and `p2`, and `p1` is passed to the base constructor in `A`.